# ESLint: 'Partial' is not defined in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, pycharm, eslint, typescript-eslint

ESLint is not recognizing `Partial` of typescript but the compiled module does not give any error.

```js
const initialState: IAuthState = {
  authenticated: false,
  processing: false,
};

const authReducer = (state: IAuthState = initialState, action: any): IAuthState => {
  const State = (newState: Partial<IAuthState>): IAuthState => ({...state, ...newState});

  switch (action.type) {
    case Actions.SIGN_IN_PROCESS_INITIATED:
      return State({processing: true});

    case Actions.SIGN_IN_PROCESS_FAILED:
      return State({processing: false});

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

I know that this can be suppressed by `// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef` but still, I want an explanation for this and a permanent solution so that I dont get this not so error *Error*.

Comment: This feels like the Typescript parser isn't setup correctly in the eslint configuration. Have you checked that?

Comment: Can you suggest what configuration is needed?

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar case some time ago and fixed it by installing `@typescript-eslint/parser` as devDependency and including it in eslint config:

```
  "extends": [..., "@typescript-eslint/parser"],
```

Comment: documentation says it needs to be used  as `parser` not `extends` in eslint config, like this: 
"parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser"

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting with other configuration parameters for `compilerOptions` one-by-one, I found out the problem for me was that I didn't have `esnext` listed under `compilerOptions.lib`.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // other config
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext" // I added this to ensure `Partial`, `Record`, and others were recognized as defined by ESLint
    ]
    // other config
  }
}
```